# Marshal.StructureToPtr without boxing

Tags: c#, reflection, marshalling, unmanaged-memory, typedreference

Is there a way to marshal a structure (possibly stored in a *TypedReference*) to unmanaged memory without actually boxing it? The type of the structure isn't known at runtime, so I can't use the generic overload of StructureToPtr (.NET 4.5.1). I can get a MethodInfo of the *StructureToPtr* overload, but there doesn't seem to be a way to invoke it passing a generic reference or a *TypedReference*.

Edit: The generic *StructureToPtr* still boxes the structure, so trying to invoke it is useless.

Comment: Why do you need the generic version of `StructureToPtr`? Edit: Even the generic version will just call the non-generic version and cause a box.

Comment: @leppie Oh, I thought the generic one does some tricks to avoid boxing. What purpose it has then, other than confuse?

Comment: Maybe there is special handling, but nothing I see in the docs... Not sure what the purpose is...

Comment: @leppie The new generic overload just calls the old overload, checked in Reflector.

Comment: The JITTER may still do some kind of optimization that is not apparent from the IL. But who knows if it is not documented :D

Comment: My flippant answer would be "use C++/CLI". When you get down to this level, you don't want to use C# (or any other generic .NET language) but something specifically designed to interoperate. Otherwise you're likely continuously fighting against an environment designed to eliminate these concerns for you. Performance-wise, marshaling tends to suck even if you do get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found the answer, the [`SafeBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safebuffer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class. It contains exactly what I wanted - structure with marshalling methods using both `TypedReference` and generic parameters. So, it's really simple then to make a wrapper:

```
public static unsafe class InteropTools
{
    private static readonly Type SafeBufferType = typeof(SafeBuffer);
    public delegate void PtrToStructureNativeDelegate(byte* ptr, TypedReference structure, uint sizeofT);
    public delegate void StructureToPtrNativeDelegate(TypedReference structure, byte* ptr, uint sizeofT);
    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static;
    private static readonly MethodInfo PtrToStructureNativeMethod = SafeBufferType.GetMethod("PtrToStructureNative", flags);
    private static readonly MethodInfo StructureToPtrNativeMethod = SafeBufferType.GetMethod("StructureToPtrNative", flags);
    public static readonly PtrToStructureNativeDelegate PtrToStructureNative = (PtrToStructureNativeDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(PtrToStructureNativeDelegate), PtrToStructureNativeMethod);
    public static readonly StructureToPtrNativeDelegate StructureToPtrNative = (StructureToPtrNativeDelegate)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(StructureToPtrNativeDelegate), StructureToPtrNativeMethod);

    private static readonly Func<Type,bool,int> SizeOfHelper_f = (Func<Type,bool,int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Type,bool,int>), typeof(Marshal).GetMethod("SizeOfHelper", flags));

    public static void StructureToPtrDirect(TypedReference structure, IntPtr ptr, int size)
    {
        StructureToPtrNative(structure, (byte*)ptr, unchecked((uint)size));
    }

    public static void StructureToPtrDirect(TypedReference structure, IntPtr ptr)
    {
        StructureToPtrDirect(structure, ptr, SizeOf(__reftype(structure)));
    }

    public static void PtrToStructureDirect(IntPtr ptr, TypedReference structure, int size)
    {
        PtrToStructureNative((byte*)ptr, structure, unchecked((uint)size));
    }

    public static void PtrToStructureDirect(IntPtr ptr, TypedReference structure)
    {
        PtrToStructureDirect(ptr, structure, SizeOf(__reftype(structure)));
    }

    public static void StructureToPtr<T>(ref T structure, IntPtr ptr)
    {
        StructureToPtrDirect(__makeref(structure), ptr);
    }

    public static void PtrToStructure<T>(IntPtr ptr, out T structure)
    {
        structure = default(T);
        PtrToStructureDirect(ptr, __makeref(structure));
    }

    public static T PtrToStructure<T>(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        T obj;
        PtrToStructure(ptr, out obj);
        return obj;
    }

    public static int SizeOf<T>(T structure)
    {
        return SizeOf<T>();
    }

    public static int SizeOf<T>()
    {
        return SizeOf(typeof(T));
    }

    public static int SizeOf(Type t)
    {
        return SizeOfHelper_f(t, true);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
int size = InteropTools.SizeOf(g);
IntPtr mem = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
InteropTools.StructureToPtr(ref g, mem);

Guid g2 = InteropTools.PtrToStructure<Guid>(mem);
```

Now, does it actually have any advantages over the non-generic object-taking methods in the `Marshal` class? It seems the `StructureToPtr` takes about 80 % less time, and `PtrToStructure` can take almost 95 % less time. Also, these methods can handle nullable types correctly.

Comment: Did you test on both x86 and x64? Performance characteristics of boxing vary between the jitters (and RyuJIT, if you want to include that). Although I suppose it really doesn't matter much -- if marshaling is your bottleneck you want to eliminate it altogether (or reduce overhead by copying batches rather than individual values).

Comment: @JeroenMostert No, but it seems I've got the results wrong. Although running in Release, the attached debugger still seems to affect the performance.

Comment: Yes -- in fact, Debug versus Release usually has no measurable impact on performance, since the amount of optimization the compiler does on the generated IL is actually fairly limited (it prefers to let the jitter do the heavy lifting). Running under a debugger, however, completely invalidates any performance tests.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've updated the results. Looks too good to be true. ☺

Comment: Microbenchmarks tend to be, but it's impossible to judge without seeing the actual benchmark code. However, this case quite simply is not interesting -- if copying 16 bytes to unmanaged memory is your bottleneck, rethink your scenario, don't focus on optimizing marshaling structures. The methods in `Marshal` aren't typically optimized for performance because they don't need to be -- if you want performance you'd use unsafe code, or C++/CLI, or arrays, or a managed implementation of whatever you're marshaling to.

Comment: @JeroenMostert As always, I am just curious. And I really like to play with TypedReference. ☺